# How to make a facebook like button refer to a dynamically generated product

Tags: php, facebook

I've developed a web site for a furniture store showing hundred of different products. I'd like to put a Facebook Like button on each of them, pointing to the specific product they like.

I'm using the standard HTML5 code generated by Facebook just after the opening body tag of my page.

Here's the code for the actual button for each product. Specific variables are added in PHP.

```
<div class="fb-like" style="background-color:#bbb; z-index:10; position:absolute; bottom:0px;" data-href="http://www.nothinfancy.ca/NF4/index.php?showmedetail=2&amp;readme=<?php print($readme);?>&amp;image=<?php print("thumbnailpix2/$image");?>" data-send="false" data-width="<?php print($skuwidth);?>" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

The variables print out correctly but when I 'like' a product, it doesn't show on my FB page even though it says 'You like this' when I look at the website.

Follow [this link](http://www.nothinfancy.ca/NF4/index.php?showmedetail=2&readme=43&editordisplay=&image=thumbnailpix2/highheelchair.jpg&baseimage=thumbnailpix2/highheelchair.jpg&i=9&m=9&thecount=29) to see an example of one of my dynamic buttons.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Set Open Graphs meta tags to gain visibility. And Remove the `data-ref` attribute, so that the *like button* will refer to current page/product.

This is detailed on [Like Button reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) page.

Comment: Thanks for that fast reply. By 'remove data-ref' do you mean remove the whole URL here?

data-href="http://www.nothinfancy.ca/NF4/index.php?showmedetail=2&amp;readme=<?php print($readme);?>&amp;image=<?php print("thumbnailpix2/$image");?>" data-send="false" data-width="<?php print($skuwidth);?>"

I don't see references to this stuff on the page you recommended. I'm a newbie to this stuff. You're going a bit over my head.

Comment: Yes. Simply, when you generate the code snippet from the form in that page, do not fill the URL field (hover on the blue question mark over the text field to read the tooltip).